# Get jar file from Android phone

Tags: android, eclipse, jar

I am having some problems with my project in Eclipse.

There were some errors in project and the best way to solve them was to re-import the project. When this was done all my files in the project were empty.

Is there some way to import my source code from my telephone on which I tested my last version of program? (with .jar file in Java)

Has anyone experienced this before?

How can I import a project with `File->Import->Existing...` and choose the name of the project and directory?

Comment: or maybe there are some jar files on my computer left from the time I build it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.jar` files usually contain no source code, but they contain class files with byte code (`.class` files, not `.java` files). Ever looked into a class file? That's not readable code, it is a couple of VM instructions and it is not possible to get your source code back from those files. You can decompile them and you will get back *some source code*, yet this is not your original source code, has no comments and sometimes is barely human readable as things like local variable names are not recoverable. So I guess the answer is rather NO.

Comment: That's a pity. But thanks